# Use the futureBuilder for main route

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I set up my app with named routes:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: "/",
      routes: {
        "/": (context) => 
          FutureBuilder(
            future: landingPage(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Widget> widget) {
              if(widget.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
                if(!widget.hasData) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: Text("No Data exists"),
                  );
                }
                return widget.data!;
              }
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        "/email-verification":(context) => const EmailVerificationPage(),
        "/login":(context) => const LoginPage(),
        "/name-age":(context) => const AgePage(),
        "/signup":(context) => const SignupPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Then I have my functions where I decide which page should be the landing page depending on how far the user has added information to their account:

```
Future<Widget> landingPage() async {
  if(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null){
    return const LoginPage();
  }
  if(!FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.emailVerified){
    return const EmailVerificationPage();
  }
  if(! await checkAge(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)){
    return const AgePage();
  }
  return const HomePage();
}

Future<bool> checkAge(String uid) async {
  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users")
    .where("uid", isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
    .where("birtDate", isNull: false)
    .get();

  if(snapshot.size > 0){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

However the futureBuilder always returns no data for some reason. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice and your video was awesome as well. What actually happened was that Firestore failed my query because I didn't have an index for it but you fixed another issue in my code so thanks.